# How to block access to a specific website for the Tor user?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Im using ubuntu, with Tor browser. I blacklisted certain unwanted websites on my router and on this computer in iptables, but I can still access them via Tor (i cant acess on regular browsers). How to block access to websites in Tor too?

Comment: I'm not sure that trying to censor an anti-censorship tool is going to be particularly easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commenter, womble, is correct.

Tor does not use the DNS (Domain Name Service) that the rest of the apps on your computer uses therefore you can't block any websites via domain requests. It also does not read your local hosts file so you can't redirect websites via that method either.

Tor, by its very nature, will not allow censorship.

Here is an option: Install Tor Browser directly and not via torbrowser-launcher for a user called "Dad". If torbrowser-launcher is installed, uninstall it.

Create a second user called "Kid1" Kid1 will not be able to run Tor Browser and therefore will be limited to using a browser with the restrictions.

Basically if you want to have an anti-censorship tool like Tor Browser available system wide, you have to understand that the trade off is that you can't censor it.